# Cannot render a card face 

Tags: fontspec, cards

I'm failing at rendering a card face: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1F0A1

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
card face: ''
\end{document}
```

In my PDF I'm getting an empty character and in the log an error message:

```
Missing character: There is no  (U+1F0A1) in font [lmroman10-regular]:+tlig;
```

I tried using the same font "MesloLGS NF" that I use in my Emacs, it renders card faces with no issues:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{MesloLGS NF}
\setmonofont{MesloLGS NF}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
card face: ''
\end{document}
```

So then I get a different error that seems to mention a different font than the one I'm trying to use:

```
Missing character: There is no  (U+1F0A1) in font [lmsans10-regular]:+tlig;!
```

I'm using the command:

```
latexmk -gg -lualatex book.tex
```

And I also tried `-xelatex`.

I'd like to be able to render any/all of the Playing Cards: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/block/U+1F0A0

Is this even possible?  How to proceed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The errors are saying that the Latin Modern sans or roman fonts don't contain the card image glyphs, which is true. In your first example, you don't load a font with the glyphs, and the default roman font is Latin Modern Roman, so that makes sense. In your second example, you change the main font to the Latin Modern Sans since you haven't set a sans font, so again it tries to find the glyphs in that font and fails.

I don't have your font, so I can't test your exact document, but if I use DejaVu Sans as the main font, everything renders as expected:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} % uncomment for error
\begin{document}
Some cards:



\end{document}
```

I can reproduce your error by uncommenting the `\renewcommand` line, which tells TeX to make the main font the default sans serif font. Since no sans serif font has been explicitly defined (using `\setsansfont`) the Latin Modern Sans font is used, and it doesn't contain the glyphs.

So your second example can be made to work in two ways: either remove the `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}` line, or change your `\setmainfont{MesloLGS NF}` to be `\setsansfont{MesloLGS NF}`. This latter solution is really identical to setting the main font to `MesloLGS NF` anyway, so it's really a redundant way to do it.

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the fast and helpful response.